# controlling sides in split seaborn violin chart

Tags: python, seaborn

having (like the example: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_violinplots.html)

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

# Load the example tips dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips = tips[(tips['day'] == 'Sun')]
# Draw a nested violinplot and split the violins for easier comparison
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
           split=True, inner="quart",
           palette={"Yes": "y", "No": "b"},
           data=tips)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

You get:

[image]

Is it possible to control the sides , i.e: specify 'no' left and 'yes' right ?

The problem I have is that when generating mupltiple plots I get images having data on different sides like:

[image]

[image]

I would like to have 'downs' left, 'ups' right on all images.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your question is unclear really. Consider rephrasing

Comment: yes, I have different code but this simple example simple fits the problem. I generate  a number of single violins. But it swaps the sides and I would like to have all the same layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, from the official [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)

> order, hue_order : lists of strings, optional
>   Order to plot the categorical levels in, otherwise the levels are
>   inferred from the data objects.

```
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",hue_order=['No','Yes'],
       split=True, inner="quart",
       palette={"Yes": "y", "No": "b"},
       data=tips)
```

[image]

Comment: That is the one!. ... I must have read over that one many times